# REST PUT multiply options to pass data - Best Practice for URI path

Tags: web-services, rest, http-put

I'm writing a service which need to support multiple ways to pass the data, my base HTTP PUT request:

PUT .../entity

but I want that the data can be passed by CSV or JSON in the body

so I thought maybe:

- first option

PUT .../entity?type=(csv|json) -> although I didn't see any best practice query params with PUT request.

- Second option:

PUT ../entity/csv

PUT ../entity/json

- Third option:

PUT ../entity 
+ Custom Header: Body-Type = (csv|json)

What do you think?

Comment: What language/framework are you using? It sounds like you are talking about the implementation on the back end. Most REST frameworks have something like a `@Consumes` to declare what data type the service accepts. I would start there.

Comment: im using PHP Kohana, 

in one time im sending CSV file, and in the next a json body.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a [content-type header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to specify the MIME type. The URI isn't meant to describe message format, you should put only filters, etc. into that. But that's just an opinion.